# Braintree Transaction Sale storing in valult and proper use of nonce and token

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I have a few questions:

Can I store the credit card/paypal method in sale but also prevent duplicates? OR do duplicates just create an error when using **storeInVaultOnSuccess**. Will a "duplicate method" error cause sale to fail?

Can I create a customer  with **Braintree_Transaction::sale**? Will a "duplicate customer" error cause sale to fail?

Is there a way to combine to do a "either/or" for **paymentMethodNonce** and **paymentMethodToken**?

Lastly security question. Does Braintree make sure the **paymenthMethodToken** for a customer matches the **customerId** of the sale? To ensure a token for one customer method cannot be used to complete sale for another customer.

```
if($paymentMethodNonce){
  if($save){
    $create=Braintree_PaymentMethod::create([
      "customerId"=>$customerId,
      "paymentMethodNonce"=>$paymentMethodNonce,
      "options"=>["failOnDuplicatePaymentMethod"=>true]
    ]);      
  }
  $sale=Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    "amount"=>$cost,
    "paymentMethodNonce"=>$paymentMethodNonce,
    "customerId"=>$customerId
  ]);
}
else if($paymentMethodToken){
  $sale=Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    "amount"=>$cost,
    "paymentMethodToken"=>$paymentMethodToken,
    "customerId"=>$customerId
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question, if you include both a `paymentMethodToken` and a `customerId` when creating a sale, we require that the `paymentMethodToken` belongs to the customer specified by the provided `customerId`. If it does not belong to the customer specified, we throw a [Transaction Error](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/php#transaction) with code `91516` (Cannot provide both payment_method_token and customer_id unless the payment_method belongs to the customer).

Answer (score 1):

You can create customers and payment methods inside the sale transaction, but they do create errors on duplicates which cause sale to fail. The best way is just to create and ignore errors

```
$create_customer=Braintree_Customer::create([
  "id"=>$id,
]);
$create_payment_method=Braintree_PaymentMethod::create([
  "customerId"=>$login,
  "paymentMethodNonce"=>$method
]);
```

Next, the only way to combine paymentMethodNonce and paymentMethodToken is to switch according to which one is being handled.

```
$TokenOrNonceType="paymentMethodToken"; or $TokenOrNonceType="paymentMethodNonce";
$sale=Braintree_Transaction::sale([
  "amount"=>$cost,
  $TokenOrNonceType=>$TokenOrNonce,
  "customerId"=>$customerId
]);
```

Lastly, I am still unsure about the last question. Does Braintree make sure the **paymenthMethodToken** for a customer matches the **customerId** of the sale? To ensure a token for one customer method cannot be used to complete sale for another customer. Thanks